# Install an additional completion function for bash

Tags: bash, software-installation, autocomplete

I have never used bash completion of todo.txt cli; however, I have decided to give it try. On the author's github, it says:

```
(Optional, since v 2.9:) Install the Bash completion, either system-wide, for all users:

      $ sudo cp todo_completion /etc/bash_completion.d/todo
or 

      put it somewhere in your home directory and source it from your .bashrc:
```

Now in the install documentation for bash completion, it says:

```
The easiest way to install this software is to use a package; it is available
in many operating system distributions.  The package's name is usually
bash-completion.  Depending on the package, you may still need to source it
from either /etc/bashrc or ~/.bashrc (or any other file sourcing those). You
can do this by simply using:

# Use bash-completion, if available
[[ $PS1 && -f /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion ]] && \
    . /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion
```

So from my understanding, which may wrong, I should put

```
# Use bash-completion, if available
    [[ $PS1 && -f /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion ]] && \
        . /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion
```

in my `~/.bashrc`. Now should I put `todo-completion` in `/usr/share/bash-completion/bash-completion`? If so, I only have `/usr/share/bash-completion` but there is a `completion` one level below `bash-completion`.

To be honest, I could be all wrong with this thought process. I have been doing numerous searches on `todo` and `bash-completion` but nothing has been too promising. So if this is all incorrect, how do I set up both up together?

Answer (score 1):

If you add the file to `/usr/share/bash-completion/` it will be overwritten by pacman when the package is next updated.

To prevent this from happening, use `~/.bash_completion`, which is sourced at the end of the main completion script. From [the FAQ](https://salsa.debian.org/debian/bash-completion/blob/master/README.md):

> Q. How can I insert my own local completions without having to
>    reinsert them every time you issue a new release?
>
> A. Put them in ~/.bash_completion, which is parsed at the end of the
>    main completion script. See also the next question.

Alternatively, for system-wide access on Arch, you can place the file in `/etc/bash_completion.d/`.

Comment: Just so I understand, I should do `sudo mkdir ~/.bash_completion && cp /path/to/todo-completion ~/.bash_completion`?

Comment: @dustin No, just copy `todo_completion` to `~/.bash_completion` and open a new terminal, it should work ootb.